# EOF exception while reading clojure file

Tags: emacs, clojure, jetty, ring, hiccup

When I run the web application in the ring jetty server, I got EOF exception, I can't fix this, since there is no clue on which line the error has occurred. I'm using compojure and hiccup on my clojure code. I'm using Emacs 23 as editor.

Here is the part of the exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: EOF while reading (core.clj:66)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5863)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
.................
............
.........
.....
```

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you've got mismatched parentheses, brackets or braces. In Emacs, try `M-x show-paren-mode`, then put your cursor on various parentheses in the file (starting with the first) to figure out which ones are unmatched.

Comment: I would recommend you to use paredit-mode - it simplify work with s-expressions greately

Comment: I agree, Alex! Never see an unmatched paren again! :-)  The only trouble is, it becomes annoying to program in non-lisps after mastering paredit...